# Cheap bound on $\zeta'(s)/\zeta(s)$ or $L'(s,\chi)/L(s,\chi)$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory

Say you are proving an explicit formula for $L(s,\chi)$ and/or the prime number theorem (in arithmetic progressions or not) in the usual way -- that is, shifting a line of integration from $\Re(s) = 1^+$ to the left. We need some kind of bound on $L'(s,\chi)/L(s,\chi)$ in the critical strip.

The usual method is a bit roundabout -- it goes through the Weierstrass-Hadamard product formula and results in a much stronger bound than what we need. It would seem to be enough to have $L'(s,\chi)/L(s,\chi) = o(|s|)$ away from zeroes -- in fact $o(|s|^2)$ is enough if you have smoothing.

Is there a way to obtain such "cheap" bounds? The case of a principal character $\chi$ may be hardest.

Comment: Well, any method would need to see the zeros as the logarithmic derivative has poles there. I am not sure what you mean by $L'(s,\chi)/L(s,\chi) = O(|s|)$ as this is false on the critical line.

Comment: I meant "O(s) away from zeroes".

Comment: How would that be false away from zeroes on the critical line?

Comment: Not clear what it means "away from zeros" as there are infinitely many zeros. How far should we be away from a given zero for your bound to be true? Also, how can you prove this bound without talking about the zeros when the statement itself talks about the zeros?

Comment: Let me be more precise. Take, say, Lemma 12.1 in Montgomery-Vaughan: $\zeta'(s)/\zeta(s) = -1/(s-1) + \sum_{\rho: |\Im \rho - \Im s|\leq 1} 1/(s-\rho) + O(\log \Im s + 4)$, where $\rho$ goes over the zeroes of $\zeta(s)$. Is it possible to give a proof of this or a weaker result of the same kind without going through the Weierstrass product formula?

Comment: Harald: Can you use Lemma $\alpha$ in section 3.9 of Titchmarsh?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Micah: I think you are right. The Lemma you quote is essentially Lemma 6.3 in Montgomery-Vaughan (is it due to Landau?).  It is enough to give a very coarse bound on $L(s,\chi)$ for $\Re s > - \epsilon$ or $\Re s > 1/2-\epsilon$ ($L(s,\chi)= O(|s|^C)$ would suffice) and to use a trivial lower bound on $L(s,\chi)$ for $\Re s = 3/2$, say. Then the sum is over zeroes $\rho$ with $|\Im \rho - \Im s|\leq 3$, but that's of course fine.

Comment: Meta-question: then why does Lemma 12.1 come so late in Montgomery-Vaughan, and why does the proof given involve results proved using the Weierstrass product formula? Are we missing something?